# Must I use either quotient or multiplication rule to find the derivative of a function?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

Here is a example to illustrate what I meant: $f(x)=\frac{3x}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}}$. We can just apply quotient rule as it is. To use multiplication rule we need to turn the function into: $3x(4x^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

But besides all these, we can just make it: $3(x^{-2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}(4x^2+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and distribute the $x$.

My question is **am I gonna lose solutions for x because of cancelation of variable?**

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $(x^{-2})^{\frac{-1}{2}}=\sqrt {x^{2}}=|x|$ and so $f(x)$ becomes:

$f(x)=\frac{3|x|}{\sqrt{4x^{2}+1}}$ which of course changes the original function.

Comment: But no for odd exponents, right?